# Run time permission not working access fine location Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am working on project where i need to access user's gps location. Due to android 6, I need run time permissions. I tried to do it , first time it asked for gps location on activity starts, but without giving me location. I am still not getting any location coordinates. Hope someone can help ?

```
public class benzinpriser_akt extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {


   public static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS_LOCATION = 1 ;
   LocationManager locationManager;
   LocationListener locationListener;
   Location currentLocation;    

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            currentLocation = location;
            System.out.println("Current Location "+ currentLocation );
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {



        } else {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS_LOCATION);
        }
    }

   // Some other code regarding listview and fetching data from database
 }



 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                System.out.println("Permission Granted");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to handle the case where you already have the permission.

Comment: Can u let me know in which part of the code I can handle it

Answer (score 0):

First of all add theese two lines to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

Then in your activity you must implement like that :

```
public class benzinpriser_akt extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener, android.location.LocationListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 20000; // 20 sec
private int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
private int DISPLACEMENT = 50; // get location per 50 meter change
protected final String TAG = "Location Service";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(yourlayout);
 //build google api client
 buildGoogleApiClient();

   } //oncreate end
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.v(TAG, "google client building");
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(thisService)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

            startListenLocation();

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
    }



}

     public void createLocationRequestWithDialog(final Activity activity){

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

    //**************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                activity, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


}

public void checkGpsPermission(Activity activity) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_ACCESS_GPS);

    }
    else
    {
        createLocationRequestWithDialog(activity);
    }


}

    protected void startListenLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisService, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //no permission , create a notification and want permission
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(thisService)
                .setContentTitle(" notification")
                .setContentText("there is no permission about using gps services, please give location permissions")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), n);
    } else {
        // permission has been granted, continue as usual

    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    }


}

 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mLastLocation != null) {
        createLocationRequestWithDialog();
        startListenLocation();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
 //TODO add other override methods , onresume, onproviderenabled etc...

}//class end
```

> Battery drain :

```
/*
    Priority                update interval      Battery drain per hour (%)     Accuracy
    HIGH_ACCURACY           5 seconds                   7.25%                   ~10 meters
    BALANCED_POWER          20 seconds                  0.6%                    ~40 meters
    NO_POWER                N/A                         small                   ~1 mile
```

*/

Comment: The code u send me before is giving more errors u can use the same code in my class above. I need gps location due to project requirements but thx for advice

Comment: I updated my answer , you can check if you want. I am telling you again i suggest you to use google location services. Cuz if you using it continuously your battery will drain much more at Android's location manager. And then this is just an answer you can improve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is just the requirements of project, otherwise i had changed it , thx again

Comment: i understand my friend . maybe this will help someone :)